# A question about Gödel's 1931 Paper.

Tags: logic

Is there a typographical error in the dover and God Created the Integers editions of Gödel's Incompleteness paper? Or is it correct?

Based on eq. 9 in part 2, I believe that there should be a negation sign over xB{17Genr} in equation 15. I know this is a esoteric, but if someone has a better translation (the translation in a source book on mathematical logic or Davies. Undecidability maybe) is it the same? Is it correct?

I should add that he merely says "by substituting p for y." And mere substitution shouldn't affect the negation in 9.

Answer (score 6):

A scan of the German original can be found at https://metalab.at/wiki/images/0/0b/Goedel.pdf. Indeed the $xB_\varkappa\ldots$ is negated in equations 9 and 15 (on page 188).

Comment: Thanks. :-) I'll be referring back to this. It's surprising that Dover and Running Press continue to republish this with the error. This error was easy to spot. Who knows how many errors I've missed. Unfortunately, I don't speak German and I'll be mainly relying on these terrible translations.

Comment: @user23648: My Dover reprint of Meltzer's translation (1992, isbn 0-486-66980-7) does have the negation bar in equation 15, but it (and several others nearby) looks curiously hand-drawn, as if it was added in freehand to the film after the text was typeset.